# 7400 chip register with common in/out pins

Tags: ttl, register, 7400

First of all, I don't know if this kind of question is allowed here, so sorry if it isn't.

I am looking for a 7400 series register which has common in and out pins (like for the RAM ou EEPROM: [image: 28C16]) with a load signal and a store signal. I searched on Google but I didn't found anything (maybe my searches are wrong).

Does it exist and if yes, what is its name/reference?

Comment: How about an 8 bit addressable latch... https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT259.pdf

Comment: Wikipedia may help, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits

Comment: Mmh, not really, I would like to be able to modify  all the content at once

Comment: Yeah, I know this list, but there's 80 different register and none of them indicate common in/out (actually, I think, I has been a bit lazy and didn't check every register...)

Comment: "I would like to be able to modify all the content at once " please don't make this a moving target question....

Comment: I showed an example with an EEPROM which can modify all the content, so I thought it was implied. But anyway, after searching again in the Wikipedia list, I found the 74299 which fit perfectly with what I want. Sorry for this useless question, I'll answer myself

Comment: EEPROM does not imply modify all content at once... I'm still not sure I understand your meaning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deeper research on the Wikipedia list of the 7400 series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits), I found out the 74299 which has common in/out pins.

I searched with the wrong keyword which should have been "bidirectionnal register".

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a register that has common input and output pins, but you can certainly wire up a '373 or '374 (8-bit latch or register with tristate outputs) to achieve that functionality:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5UBPj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>